# Set MySQL fetch mode globaly

Tags: php, mysql, adodb-php

We have recently migrated our application to a new server. Since our migration we are experiencing a lot of `PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()` errors. I already found out, that this might be related to our SQL statements returning objects instead of arrays in the new environment.
As we are using ADODB I also already found out, that the behaviour is because of `$ADODB_FETCH_MODE`. In our application it is set to `ADODB_FETCH_DEFAULT` . As the [documentation](https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:adodb_fetch_mode) states that means

> The recordset is returned in the default provided by the PHP driver. Use of this value is not recommended if writing cross-database applications

So my assumption is the "new" PHP driver has a different configuration than the old one. But how can I find out what the default config of the PHP driver is and how to change it without changing actual application code?

Thanks!

Comment: The driver and its defaults are compiled into PHP, so unless you want to recompile from scratch I'd suggest adding a couple new lines to set the value you want rather than relying on the default.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is was hoping, that there is a way to config it in the php.ini or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the ADOdb fetch mode you need, instead of relying on the default. This can be done globally, e.g.

```php
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
```

Or per connection

```php
$db->setFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
```